# How to call different JS functions on different clicks on a button?

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to call a JS function that triggers a popup on the first click of the button after page load.  And then a different function on the second click, I have no idea how to make that work and anything I've found on it has been difficult to adapt.

This is the popup: https://jsfiddle.net/d80tcw5f/

Below is the element for the current button.

```
    <a ng-class="{true : 'cart-checkout-button disabled', false : 'cart-checkout-button'}[data.DisableCheckout]" ng-click="PlcaOrder()" >
                                        <span class="payment-label">{{data.PlaceOrderText}}&nbsp;</span>
                             <span aria-hidden="true" class=" icon-arrow-right2"></span> </a>
```

"PlcaOrder()" is the function that redirects to the payment gateway, which I need to happen on the second click.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it would be to create a 3rd function for routing

```
var func1 = ...;
var func2 = ...;

var func3 = function(e) {
  if (!this.firstClick) {
    this.firstClick = true;
    func1(e);
  } else {
    func2(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: So I'm actually not even sure if this works yet, because despite it working in JS fiddle, the popup doesn't work on the site, the button just becomes unclickable.

Comment: @BLiTz I'm sorry about that, but from what you've posted, I don't think I/we can help you with that issue

Comment: Hey!  So this worked with a little tinkering, the problem I encountered was that I was unable to close the popup using the button, because the style was inactive due to the switch.  https://jsfiddle.net/a7jn0wue/  Thanks!

Comment: @BLiTz Good! When you have a chance, please click the check mark next to the question to mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function that gets called on the first click just change the value of the ng-click attribute to the second function that you want calling e.g. PlcaOrder()

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I get your point correctly but try somthing like setting a boolean on the click event. Once you click on the button, set it to true, then call to second function (set the second function to be called only if your boolean is set to true). Then after the second function call, reset the boolean back to false.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the number of clicks in a variable and then increment that number every time the button is clicked. Then, depending on the number of the variable do something. Example:

```js
let clicks = 0;

function myFunction() {
  clicks++;
  if (clicks === 1) {
    console.log("button clicked for the first time")
  } else {
    console.log("button clicked more than once")
  }
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch style.

```
var clicks = 0;

function clickSwitcher() {
  switch (clicks) {
    case 0:
      console.log("click0", "Do something!");
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log("click1", "Make a thing.");
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log("click2", "Drink!");
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log("click3", "Test the loop.");
      break;
    case 4:
      console.log("click4", "Sleep.");
      clicks = 0 //and restart
      break;
  }
  clicks++;
}
```